# Uniformly convergence and bounded

Tags: uniform-convergence

I know if {$f_n$} is a sequence of bounded function converge uniformly to f on E, then f is bounded on E. I wonder if it is true for pointwise convergence. So here is my supposed proof:

if $f$ is not bounded above, $\forall c$, there $\exists x_c$ st $f(x_c)>c$,

Since $f_n$ converges to f pointwise, for this $x_c$, pick $\epsilon=1$, there $\exists N$, for $\forall n \ge N$, $f_n(x_c)>f(x_c)-1>c-1$.

Thus $\forall n\ge N$, $f_n$ is not bounded above. We have contradiction.

Thus f is bounded above. By the same way f is bounded below.

This proof seems correct to me and thanks for your time.

Comment: It is not true for pointwise convergence unless by "bounded" you mean "uniformly bounded."

Comment: Consider $f_n(x) = nx^n$ on $(0,1).$

Comment: Or consider any positive unbounded function $f(x)$ and set $f_n(x)=\min\{n,f(x)\}$.

Comment: Your proof is incorrect basically because you've mixed up the order of quantifiers. All you've proved is that $f_n$ isn't bounded by $c-1$ itself for $n\ge N$; you haven't proved that it isn't bounded by *something*. (Think about this in conjunction with my example in the above comment.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments above. I have found the error in my proof:

$\forall c$, $f_n$ is not bounded above by  $c-1$ for all $n\ge N(c)$. When we change $c$, the corresponding $N(c)$ will change, so we can not show $f_n$ is not bounded above by any $c-1$.

However, if convergence is uniform, we will be able to find a common $N$ that is independent of $c$ and get the result we want.